# Simple method validation

Tags: java

I have this method where I validate and ID and I'm getting an issue with it.
The ID must follow these rules to be valid:

- Has 6 chars exactly
- Must starts with an A, E or P.

Here's the code:

```
public static String getCartId(String cartId) {
    Boolean correctId = false;

    while (!correctId) {
        cartId = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type the Cart ID:");
        cartId = cartId.trim();
        cartId = cartId.toUpperCase();
        char c = cartId.charAt(0);

        // VALIDATION
        if (cartId.length() != 6)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cart ID must have only 6 chars, type it again.");
        else if (c != 'A' || c != 'E' || c != 'P')
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Cart ID, type it again.");
        else
            correctId = true;
    }
    return cartId;
}
```

If I type, let's say, **aaaaaa**, it ends up saying that this ID is not valid.

Any ideas of what is wrong?

Comment: Nothing, per your specification `aaaaaa` starts with a lower case `a` which is not in the allowed set of `A`, `E` or `P`.

Comment: but before getting the first letter, I put the method toUpperCase(), the variable c is storing 'A'

Comment: Are you test my answer?

Comment: @Abdelhak yes, if I type AAAAAA it still shows that it's not valid

Comment: for me if I type it print AAAAAA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to replace this:

```
  else if (c != 'A' || c != 'E' || c != 'P')
```

With using `&&` instead of `||` like this:

```
  else if (c != 'A' && c != 'E' && c != 'P')
```

Comment: Thanks, it work perfectly now ... I'm still learning java I thought using OR would make sense instead of using AND, but using && worked like a charm, still need to learn some logic hehe, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it would better to you to use regexp like this :

```
if (cartId.matches("(?s)([AEP]{1}[A-Z0-9]{5})")) {
...}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have 2 validations like this, one for length and one for the first letter? I'd like to inform the user what was the problem with the ID :-)

Comment: You can check string length before regexp revision, if you need, it is not restricted))

Comment: Anyway to use regexp here is more comfortable, because you don't need char variable, and you don't have to check multiple parameter. For example today your ID must start with A, E or P, and if tomorrow the amount of letters will increase your if statement could became bulky.. and so on

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm in the beginning of learning Java and still not checked the Regex thing, but for sure it would be a better solution as I can see here :-)

Answer (score 1):

This situation is happening as, the **||** is **short-circuit** operator.[Read this](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)

In your case

`else if (c != 'A' || c != 'E' || c != 'P')`

Here `c != 'A'` returns **false**. So it checks for next condition `c != 'E'` which returns **true** to it, and hence it sets your id as invalid.

Try to replace it with **AND** as if &&

```
else if (c != 'A' && c != 'E' && c != 'P')
```

OR if you want to try another approach, just google about using regular expression, and use **[ACP].....** as regex. It will decrease your code to just two lines validation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now it makes sense to me :-)

Comment: I already marked the answer as complete earlier, but for sure yours is upvoted, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have used

```
(c != 'A' || c != 'E' || c != 'P')
```

which is not right.

As per your requirement you want that if c is not equal to either A or E or P,
only then it should print it as invalid. But what || does is that, it returns true if any one of the given conditions is true. It means that if c='A', the first condition is false, but the other two conditions are true, so the value to the whole if statement is returned as true.
Replacing it by

```
(c != 'A' && c != 'E' && c != 'P')
```

will help as it returns true only if ALL the conditions are true. So if c='A', the first condition is false, which returns false to the whole if statement.
Hope you get my point.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yap I just understood it later, still learning Java, thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

You are converting the entire string to upper case before you are validating the first letter. So if you input aaaaaa you will be trying to validate AAAAAA

Comment: I convert all to upper case, then after I store the first letter in the variable c, so the variable c has the letter 'A' and then it is validated, isn't this correct? sorry still learning Java

Comment: It depends if you want your validation to be case sensitive or not. If you don't care and want aaaaaa and AAAAAA to both pass as input it is perfectly fine.